# Why GDAL can't open big geo Tiff?

Tags: python, tiff, gdal

python with anaconda .gdal version =2.2.2  libtiff version =4.09 ,Win 7 ,RAM =8G:

After update packages, I find  my program doesn't work. In Anaconda prompt ,It shows ‘not definite GDAL_DATA’, So I add env variable with  ‘%~dp0......\Library\share\gdal’ .Ok,It doesn't tell me ‘not definite GDAL_DATA’.But the program does not work ~~ :(

```
from osgeo import gdal
import numpy as np
ds = gdal.Open('G:\Soil_GridV2\Sand\SNDPPT_M_sl1_250m_ll.tif')
channel = np.array(ds.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray())
```

and then :

```
 from osgeo import gdal
 import numpy as np
 ds = gdal.Open('G:\Soil_GridV2\Sand\SNDPPT_M_sl1_250m_ll.tif')
 channel = np.array(ds.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray())
 Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "<ipython-input-18-343e96de9e31>", line 4, in <module>
 channel = np.array(ds.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray())

 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetRasterBand'**
```

So I check the Variable in spyder ，and find ds is None value.SO I guess the GDAL now broken can't open tiff?  SO i try it again with a small tiff file(about 67.8 M) .successed! SO I find my GDAL can't open big Geo tiff file 
such as first file (about 2.15G)

So ,should I do to fix it or repalce it with other libs? :)

Comment: Try `gdal.UseExceptions()` before `gdal.Open()` to see what's wrong.

Comment: Are you on a 32bits system ? If so maybe are you hitting some kind of [2GB limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2_GB_limit) ?

Comment: My system is 64 bits .

Comment: I add  `gdal.UseExceptions()` before `gdal.Open()` ,but `RuntimeError: This is a BigTIFF file.  BigTIFF is not supported by this version of GDAL and libtiff.`  @ mgc  , @cgohlke

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Have solved it by update GDAL 2.2.4 with pip command.  Note: Dont use conda update command ,because  packages2.2.2 is not support big tiff.

Comment: Its not the version of GDAL but the version of libtif used when compiling. GDAL 2.2.2 does support BigTIFF, but just as 2.2.4, only when its compiled with a recent version of libtif. I'm pretty sure the GDAL builds on the conda-forge channel have support for it. See:
http://www.gdal.org/frmt_gtiff.html

Comment: Thanks comment .I Knew that  GDAL (>2.0 )and Libtiff (>4.0) can open big tiff data.With the GDAL =2.2.2 and Libtiff =4.0.9  anaconda  provided,but I failed.  When install GDAL2.2.4 ,I am required install VC++14 build tool .SO that confused me . SO I suspect GDAL 2.2.2 in Anaconda can't good match with Libtiff.